# Cypher - multiple queries on result set

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have written a cypher query that returns a set of results (resultList).  I then want to query resultList to create three further result sets based on values within resultList using WHERE.

I have the following cypher:

```
MATCH (u:User{username:'student1'})
MATCH (qc:QuestionCollection{id:'937ac2cc-299a-4e65-ab0b-4d514c23e743'})-[c:CONTAINS]->(q:Question)

OPTIONAL MATCH (q)<-[:ATTEMPTING]-(a:Attempt)<-[:MADE]-(u)

WITH q, a, c
ORDER BY a.attemptedDateTime DESC

WITH 
q, 
c,
COLLECT(a.attemptNo)[..1][0] as attempt
ORDER BY attempt desc, c.questionNumber asc

WITH 
COLLECT({
    q: q,
    lastAttempt: attempt
}) as fullOrderedList

UNWIND fullOrderedList as resultList

return resultList //I WOULD LIKE TO QUERY resultList TO GIVE THREE RESULT SETS HERE
```

How would I go about this please?

Thanks very much!

Comment: What is your problem? explain more please

Comment: Instead of just returning resultList as I do above I would like to query resultList three times using a WHERE clause to get three seperate result sets.  Thanks :)

Comment: You may want to look at [filter()](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/functions/list/#functions-filter) and [extract()](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/functions/list/#functions-extract) functions for filtering a list (without changing the original list) as well as extracting certain elements from the objects in the list.

Comment: Thank you @InverseFalcon - I had a play with these, but they are for lists so it was tricky to do what I was needing.  It was interesting digging into those a bit though, so thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used case and tried this on my data set:

```
MATCH (g:Group)
WITH COLLECT(g) AS my_set
UNWIND my_set AS g
WITH g
RETURN COLLECT(CASE WHEN g.status='APPROVED' THEN g END) AS APPROVED_GROUP, COLLECT(CASE WHEN g.status='PENDING' THEN g END) AS PENDING_GROUP
```

this will return 2 separate set, try this solution, hope it help you

Comment: Interesting, thank you, I'll have a go with this tomorrow morning.  Thanks for your time.  Greatly appreciated!

Comment: Glad to hear that

Answer (score 1):

You can filter and extract on the list itself, no need to UNWIND it:

```
...
WITH 
COLLECT({
    q: q,
    lastAttempt: attempt
}) as fullOrderedList

WITH fullOrderedList, 
 [entry in fullOrderedList WHERE <condition 1 here>] as firstList, 
 [entry in fullOrderedList WHERE <condition 2 here>] as secondList, 
 [entry in fullOrderedList WHERE <condition 3 here>] as thirdList
...
```

This is called [list comprehension](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/3.3/cypher/syntax/lists/#cypher-list-comprehension). If you needed a custom projection of the map contents then you could project that out as needed using the syntax provided in the link.

Comment: Thank you.  I actually tried this as it looked ideal, but couldn't get it to work for some reason.  I seem to remember a message saying something like "Type error - expected list and got map" or similar.  I managed to get it to work using the CASE approach outlined above. I'll have another play though, as this will be very helpful in a lot of situations.  Thank you very much!